# How do I specify a timespan as a key in an unique constraint for multiple columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table where I add thousands of rows each time I update. Each row describes the current value of a single item.

I want to add a constraint that only allows 1 insert for a certain ItemID for a certain timespan, for example an hour.

In other words I would like one column in my table the *"itemID"* and a *"timespan"* be a unique constraint for my table.

So I thought I would somehow add something like this:

```
BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 HOUR) AND NOW() AS timespan
```

When I alter my table *(the "itemID" is irrelevant, just a column in my table")*

```
ALTER TABLE `items_update` ADD UNIQUE `unique_timespan`(`itemID`, `timespan`);
```

Can it be done? Or do I have to make a nested INSERT query that checks for this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your solution is incorrect, but you should provide more context. What are you trying to do, what is an itemId, what does your schema look like, etc.

Comment: Of course I know that my code is incorrect hence my question. 
The itemID is irrelevant it could be anything. It's just a column in my table. The problem is the "timespan".
I want a unique part of my multi column constraint to be a timespan if that was unclear.

Comment: Try to put yourself in our shoes, we have no idea what you are working on. Provide context as to what you're trying to do. For example, it's not clear why you would want to 'avoid inserting a row with the same itemID to frequently.' Or what you are adding that `BETWEEN ... ` code to

Comment: I've updated my description some, I am not adding the BETWEEN code anywere, thats just the behaviour I'd like to have as one of my keys in the unique constraint. I could go around this problem with a nested query, I just wondered if this was possible. It's unlikely that the value has changed if it's only gone like 5 minutes since last update so I it will most likely be duplicate data.

Comment: So you have a query that works, but you are looking for a more elegant solution? In that case you should definitely include that working query.

Comment: @wvdz Well, ok no I don't have that, but I know how to do it but it feels ineffective, then I have to check if the table has a row with the same itemID as the one I am trying to add and also check if it was added the last hour, in that query I would use the "BETWEEN" code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106918/discussion-between-wvdz-and-sprazer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add a unique constraint that only allows one `ItemID` per time interval, say an hour. You can do this by using a truncated timestamp. `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` returns 'seconds since 1-1-1970'. If you do integer division with (60*60), you get 'hours since 1-1-1970'. This you can use for your constraint:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (ItemId, timespan)
VALUES (1, FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() / 60 / 60));

ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (ItemId, timespan);
```

This solution is very flexible, it easily allows you to use any time interval you want, say 35m or 1 day 1 hour and 1 minute.

You could also do the truncation in your constraint, but this might cause performance issues on large datasets.

```
 ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (ItemId, FLOOR(updatedTime / 60 / 60));
```

Comment: Perfect, this was the solution I was looking for. 
Well the most awesome solution would be an solution witch didn't need an extra column. But this will do, thanks a lot!

Comment: I added a solution that doesn't require you to add a new column, provided that you are already storing a timestamp.

Comment: Amazing! That was EXACTLY the query I was looking for!

Comment: Well it was exactly what I was looking for, but I can't get it to work. My timestamp is in the format "2016-03-21 14:07:52"